# A dataflow job fails and prints a strange error message

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to build an Apache Beam pipeline that reads the data from the PostgreSQL table and writes it in Avro format to the GCS bucket.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io.avroio import WriteToAvro
from beam_nuggets.io import relational_db

from gcs.options import IngestionOptions
from gcs.schemas.providers import get_schema_by_table


def parse_record(record) -> dict:
    record["registration_date"] = record["registration_date"].timestamp()
    return record


def _get_resulting_path(ingestion_bucket, ingestion_date, table):
    year = ingestion_date[0:4]
    month = ingestion_date[4:6]
    day = ingestion_date[6:8]
    hour = ingestion_date[8:10]
    minute = ingestion_date[10:12]
    return "/".join([
        f"gs://{ingestion_bucket}", table,
        year, month, day, hour, minute,
        f"result-{ingestion_date}-{table}.avro"
    ])


def _get_query(table: str) -> str:
    return f"select * from {table}"


def execute_pipeline(options: IngestionOptions) -> None:
    table = options.table
    schema = get_schema_by_table(table)
    query = _get_query(table)
    result_path = _get_resulting_path(options.ingestion_bucket, options.ingestion_date, table)

    source_config = relational_db.SourceConfiguration(
        drivername="postgresql",
        host=options.host,
        port=options.port,
        username=options.user,
        password=options.password,
        database=options.dbname,
    )

    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        records = p | "Reading example records from database" >> relational_db.ReadFromDB(
            source_config=source_config,
            table_name=table,
            query=query
        )
        records | "Parsing records" >> beam.Map(parse_record) \
                | "Write to GCS" >> WriteToAvro(f"{result_path}", schema, file_name_suffix=".arvo")
```

I'm using **beam_nuggets** library to get records from DB.

This code works perfectly fine when I run it locally with **DirectRunner**:

```
python exec.py \
    --host ... \
    --user ... \
    --password ... \
    --dbname ... \
    --table ... \
    --ingestion_bucket ...
```

However, I can't run it with Dataflow Runner. The pipeline is executed with the following command:

```
python exec.py \
    --host ... \
    --user ... \
    --password ... \
    --dbname ... \
    --table ... \
    --ingestion_bucket ... \
    --runner DataflowRunner \
    --project ... \
    --region ... \
    --temp_location ... \
    --staging_location ...
```

Dataflow jobs started in GCP console and then failed after 5 minutes with the following error:

> Error message from worker: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/dill_pickler.py", line 418, in loads return dill.loads(s) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 275, in loads return load(file, ignore, **kwds) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 270, in load return Unpickler(file, ignore=ignore, **kwds).load() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 472, in load obj = StockUnpickler.load(self) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 462, in find_class return StockUnpickler.find_class(self, module, name) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'beam_nuggets' During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 295, in _execute response = task() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 370, in  lambda: self.create_worker().do_instruction(request), request) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 629, in do_instruction return getattr(self, request_type)( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 660, in process_bundle bundle_processor = self.bundle_processor_cache.get( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 491, in get processor = bundle_processor.BundleProcessor( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 904, in **init** self.ops = self.create_execution_tree(self.process_bundle_descriptor) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 983, in create_execution_tree return collections.OrderedDict([( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 986, in  get_operation(transform_id))) for transform_id in sorted( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 819, in wrapper result = cache[args] = func(*args) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 965, in get_operation transform_consumers = { File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 966, in  tag: [get_operation(op) for op in pcoll_consumers[pcoll_id]] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 966, in  tag: [get_operation(op) for op in pcoll_consumers[pcoll_id]] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 819, in wrapper result = cache[args] = func(*args) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 965, in get_operation transform_consumers = { File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 966, in  tag: [get_operation(op) for op in pcoll_consumers[pcoll_id]] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 966, in  tag: [get_operation(op) for op in pcoll_consumers[pcoll_id]] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 819, in wrapper result = cache[args] = func(*args) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 965, in get_operation transform_consumers = { File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 966, in  tag: [get_operation(op) for op in pcoll_consumers[pcoll_id]] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 966, in  tag: [get_operation(op) for op in pcoll_consumers[pcoll_id]] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 819, in wrapper result = cache[args] = func(*args) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 970, in get_operation return transform_factory.create_operation( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 1267, in create_operation return creator(self, transform_id, transform_proto, payload, consumers) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 1614, in create_par_do return _create_pardo_operation( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 1657, in _create_pardo_operation dofn_data = pickler.loads(serialized_fn) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 51, in loads return desired_pickle_lib.loads( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/dill_pickler.py", line 422, in loads return dill.loads(s) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 275, in loads return load(file, ignore, **kwds) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 270, in load return Unpickler(file, ignore=ignore, **kwds).load() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 472, in load obj = StockUnpickler.load(self) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 462, in find_class return StockUnpickler.find_class(self, module, name) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'beam_nuggets'

Although I don't have this issue when I use the direct runner, the error says that the beam_nuggets module is not found. Furthermore, the "missing" module can change from run to run, now it's beam_nuggets, but next time it may be something else.

Could somebody help me with that?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer after a thorough investigation. According to the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/#local-or-nonpypi):

> When the Python SDK submits the pipeline for execution to a remote runner, the pipeline contents, such as transform user code, is serialized (or pickled) into a bytecode using libraries that perform the serialization (also called picklers). The default pickler library used by Beam is dill. To use the cloudpickle pickler, supply the --pickle_library=cloudpickle pipeline option. The cloudpickle support is currently experimental.

> By default, global imports, functions, and variables defined in the main pipeline module are not saved during the serialization of a Beam job. Thus, one might encounter an unexpected NameError when running a DoFn on any remote runner. To resolve this, supply the main session content with the pipeline by setting the --save_main_session pipeline option. This will load the pickled state of the global namespace onto the Dataflow workers (if using DataflowRunner). For example, see Handling NameErrors to set the main session on the DataflowRunner.

> Managing the main session in Python SDK is only necessary when using dill pickler on any remote runner. Therefore, this issue will not occur in DirectRunner.

> Since serialization of the pipeline happens on the job submission, and deserialization happens at runtime, it is imperative that the same version of pickling library is used at job submission and at runtime. To ensure this, Beam typically sets a very narrow supported version range for pickling libraries. If for whatever reason, users cannot use the version of dill or cloudpickle required by Beam, and choose to install a custom version, they must also ensure that they use the same custom version at runtime (e.g. in their custom container, or by specifying a pipeline dependency requirement).

The problem was that when you submit the job it doesn't mean that all the dependencies will be automatically installed. In my case, I prepared a docker image with all required libraries and added the following flags to the command described in my original post:

```
--save_main_session True \
--experiments=use_runner_v2 \
--sdk_location=container \
--sdk_container_image=...
```